# (Intermediate) normal extension is stable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My questions is about this famous result:

> Let $L\supset N \supset F$ be a tower of field extensions where $N$ is normal. For any $\sigma \in Gal(L/F), \sigma(N)=N$.

The following is what I have done which may not be helpful

It suffices to show that $\sigma(N)\subset N$. Let $\{u_i\}$ be a basis of $N/F$ and $f_i\in N[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $u_i$ by the algebraicity of $N/F$. It follows from the normality of $N$ that $N$ is a splitting field of $\{f_i\}$. The above is the only thing I can get from the normality and I can't proceed from here.

Comment: What is your definition of $N$ being normal? Is $N/K$ normal or $L/N$?

Comment: @B.Swan N/F is normal. The definition is the same as the one in Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result proves it after restricting the homomorphisms in $Gal(L/F)$ to $N$ and seeing that $L \subseteq \overline{N}$:

> Let $N/F$ be normal, then $\phi(N)=N$ for all $F$-homomorphisms $\phi: N \rightarrow \overline{N}$.

Proof:

Let $\{u_i | i \in I \}$ be a generating system of $N/F$. Let $f_i = \mu_{x_i, F}$. Since $N/F$ is normal, those polynomials split over $N$. Let $R$ be the set of all roots of those polynomials. Then $F(R)=N$.

For any $x \in R$ and any $F$-homomorphism $\phi$, it holds that $\phi(x)$ will be a root of some $f_i$. Since $N=F(R)$ it follows that $\phi(N) \subseteq N$.

If $x_1, ..., x_n$ are the roots of some $f_i$, then any $F$-homomorphism $\phi$ will permute those roots, so $\phi(x_1), ..., \phi(x_n)$ are roots of $f_i$. Thus $N \subseteq \phi(N)$.

Let me know if everything is clear.

Comment: In the statement (yellow), do you mean $\phi: \overline{N} \rightarrow \overline{N}$? $\phi: N \rightarrow \overline{N}$ seems to be much weaker than the thing I asked about.

Comment: I mean $\phi: N \rightarrow \overline{N}$. You are asking: What happens when I use a $F$-homomorphism on elements of $N$. So we consider maps $N \rightarrow \overline{N}$.

Comment: @NoOne do you understand why that is sufficient? If not feel free to ask questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just voted up. I will rethink about it in the next few days when I have time