# Confusion about a statement in this theorem concerning normal field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

We were given a proof in class that is as follows:

Given a finite extension $E/F$ the following are equivalent

1) $E/F$ is normal

2) If $\alpha \in E$ then the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ splits over $E$

3) If $L/E$ and $\sigma \in {\rm Gal}(E/F)$ then $\sigma(E)=E$

4) $E$ is a splitting field for some $m \in F[x]$

I understand 1,2 and 4 but I don't understand 3.

I am really confused by the L as it seems to play no role in the second half of the sentence(I think maybe there's some typo here).

Could anyone please tell me the correct statement/ explain its meaningfulness, please?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380437/k-is-a-splitting-field-iff-any-irreducible-polynomial-with-a-root-in-k-sp) might be helpful. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I think it needs to be $\sigma \in Gal(L/F)$, because otherwise the statement is trivial.. of course $\sigma(E)=E$ under an automorphism $\sigma: E \rightarrow E$

Comment: @B.Swan yes that is what I thought it might be, then it would be saying that if we have a field extension $E/F$ and a further field extension $L/E$, then we can consider a tower of extensions $L/E/F$ and the galois group of this extension will have automorphisms in it which fix the two lower fields. Do you think that's correct ?

Comment: $F$ is stable by definition, $E$ is stable because it is normal, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152264/intermediate-normal-extension-is-stable)